retrieving a keyring with gpg takes too long behind a proxy
I have problems installing the software PCAT from qualcomm. The step to retrive the mono keyring fails:
sudo gpg --homedir /tmp --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

With the default proxy it does not work at all, so i created the file /tmp/gpg.conf with the content:
keyserver-options "timeout=40 http-proxy=http://myCompanyProxy.com:3128"

The above command executed by it's own works now but it takes several hours and this leads to a timeout if it is executed inside the PCAT installation. PCAT aborts the execution after 30 minutes.
Any ideas how to solve it and why it's so slow ?
